# How to get next values in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I have hash for example

```
{ 1 => 5, 3 => 6, 5 => 5, 8 => 10, 11 => 11}
```

and I have one key - 5, and I need get hash with next three key-value. in this case result will be:

```
{ 8 => 10, 11 => 11, 1 => 5}
```

How i can do this?

Comment: What data structure is better in this case?

Answer (score 1):

That is not a usual use case for a hash table. The whole point is to be able to look up *specific* keys efficiently, not iterate over keys in sequence.

If you want to do that, you'll need to choose another data structure, either instead of a hash or alongside the hash (if you still wish for efficient lookup).

If you know that they're integer keys, you could test for the existence of subsequent ones until you find three but that's pretty inefficient, *especially* if the current one is the second highest, for example. You would be better maintaining a different data structure.

Comment: What data structure is better in this case?

Answer (score 0):

as others have said you can't get the 'next' pair of values.  If you're looking specifically for numerically ordered pairs where the keys are all numbers, you could do something like this:

```
h = { 1 => 5, 3 => 6, 5 => 5, 8 => 10, 11 => 11}
sorted_keys = h.keys.sort

sorted_keys.each do |key|
  p "#{key} = #{h[key]}"
end
```

which returns:

```
"1 = 5"
"3 = 6"
"5 = 5"
"8 = 10"
"11 = 11"
```

Answer (score -2):

**You can't.**

Ruby hashes are unordered. There's no reliable "next" key/value.

Comment: As it happens, they _are_ ordered. But that's implementation detail.